# React Native project Ndk issue

Tags: react-native

am Running the Existing code in React Native Project installed ndk and added in user variable and system variables.
After Executing the code it displays.

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
> No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
> Android gradle plugin: 7.3.1
> Gradle: 6.7

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Location specified by ndk.dir (/Users/indgi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653) did not contain a valid NDK and
and couldn't be used

am running the existing code in react native after executing the code i got an ndk issue.

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
> No AAR for react-native-reanimated found. Attempting to build from source.
> Android gradle plugin: 7.3.1
> Gradle: 6.7
> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-reanimated:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Location specified by ndk.dir (/Users/indgi/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/25.2.9519653) did not contain a valid NDK and and couldn't be used